# Clearing static variables in a struct/ class

Tags: ios, swift, struct, static

I have a struct with some static fields as below.

```
struct User {
    static var userId: String?
    static var email: String?
    static var phone: String? 
}
```

When the user logs in, these variables are set and used in other view controllers. When the user logs out, I would like to clear all those details. Is there a quick way to clear or should I individually clear them like

```
User.userId = ""
User.email = ""
User.phone = ""
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having static variables you could have an optional static shared `User` variable and set it to `nil` when user is logged out:

```
struct User {

    static var shared: User?

    var userId: String?
    var email: String?
    var phone: String?
}

User.shared = nil // user logged out
User.shared = User(userId: ..., email: ..., phone: ...) // user logged in
```

Comment: And is there any possibility for this "shared" variable to be cleared up at any time during app's run

Comment: @Sujal `User.shared = User()`

Answer (score 1):

You can set a function in the struct to do that or better to set user to `nil` and check for nil logic in your app